# Adding textbox to the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and in the gridview i want to add textboxes in the first row dynamically(for search). But I get an error saying expected type is INT32.

```
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < gridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.Attributes["placeholder"] = gridview1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            tb1.CssClass = "search_textbox";
            if (i != 0)
            {
                cell.Controls.Add(tb1);

            }
            dr[i] = cell;                
        }

        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 1);
        gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        gridview1.DataBind();
```

Can anyone please guide me, how to add a textbox to the first row in the gridview ?

Comment: have you tried a google search look up ItemTemplates on the internet.. plenty of working examples out there on the web..

Comment: @MethodMan Something like this `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
for(int i =0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
{
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
}`

Comment: Are you planning on doing serverside or client side filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this solution which implements filtering in gridview. Hope that can give you some direction.

[ASP.NET Gridview with Filter in Header using Reflection and LINQ-TechnoBird's Blog](http://technobird.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/aspnet-gridview-with-filter-in-header.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, link only answers are not really acceptable. If the link dies, your answer becomes useless to future visitors. Please provide at least an outline of the techniques the linked article used.